# ERROR: JAVA_HOME al querer ejecutar un archivo .sh

Tags: java, linux, rutas, linux-mint

necesito instalar un programa que desbloquea bootloader de teléfonos Xiaomi, sin embargo, siguiendo los pasos del desarrollador, llego a éste punto donde ejecuto el `sudo ./MiUnlockTool.sh` y aparece lo siguiente:

```
    ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Creo haber instalado bien Java, siguiendo las instrucciones de su página, pero evidentemente algo hice mal o directamente no hice. La versión de Java es jre1.8.0_201

Luego de dar con un video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEaWqHIuc4w&t=37s) terminé logrando que me diga que mi directorio es tal, pero no hubo cambios en el resultado final:

```
patriciosam@Patricio-DELL ~ $ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_201: Es un directorio
patriciosam@Patricio-DELL ~ $ cd /usr/miunlockxiaomi/MiUnlockTool
patriciosam@Patricio-DELL /usr/miunlockxiaomi/MiUnlockTool $ sudo ./MiUnlockTool.sh
[sudo] password for patriciosam: 

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

patriciosam@Patricio-DELL /usr/miunlockxiaomi/MiUnlockTool $ $PATH
bash: /bin:/home/patriciosam/bin:/home/patriciosam/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con esto?

Muchas gracias como siempre y disculpen tanta ignorancia en el tema.

Comment: la respuesta amigo, no va en la misma pregunta eso no es válido entonces revertí tu publicación quitándola; entonces usa el espacio de abajo la zona de respuestas para colocar tu solución

Comment: ya mismo lo corrijo, pido disculpas

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294705/librerias-de-javafx

Answer (score 2):

La solución es instalar javafx en éste caso, de la siguiente manera:

```
sudo apt install openjfx
```

Luego de eso, corrió perfecto el programa.

Answer (score 1):

Debes revisar la versión que tienes instalada (en caso de tener alguna instalada con:

```
java -version
```

EN caso de no tener ninguna instalada, haz un update/upgrade del sistema mediante sudo y luego haces la instalación limpia

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

despues solo tienes que configurar mediante parámetro la variable JAVA_HOME con este comando:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

te dará varias opciones y eliges la que necesites (normalmente es la 0 la que corresponde si no tienes ninguna instalada)