# Librerias de JavaFX

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx

Intento realizar un programa utilizando javafx desde la terminal y vi. Mi problema es que no sé como instalar las librerias de JavaFX. Instalé java desde el JDK de Oracle pero no contenia dichas librerias e intenté instalar Openjfx pero sigue dandome error al compilar ya que no reconoce las librerías de JavaFX. Anteriormente tenia OpenJdk pero tenia el mismo problema con JavaFx, ¿Que debería hacer?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: detalles de version de java e instalacion de openjfx]

Comment: java fx tiene ya tiempo que no pertenece al jdk, te recomiendo descargarlo desde la página de openjfx  o similares

Answer (score 1):

Primero le indicas a tu sistema el Path o donde se encuentran las librerías JavaFx:

```
export PATH_TO_FX=path-to/javafx-sdk-11/lib
```

Sustituyes path-to por la ruta en tu sistema.

---

Para compilar usas:

```
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HelloFX.java
```

Si tu app no usa archivos .fxml quitas el javafx.fxml de la línea anterior.

---

Para ejecutar tu App:

```
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX
```

En esta página oficial de OpenJFX puedes encontrar diferentes formas hacer funcionar tu App según tus necesidades: [Guía sobre OpenJFX -en ingles](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction)